# Pipe separated vs separate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL as the database for a Laravel application. Consider a table structure of following-

`id
brand_id
numbers`

Considering for against every brand_id there are around 5k numbers. I am unsure between the following approaches

1. Store all 5k numbers in a single record pipe separated
2. Store each of the 5k numbers as a separate record

Clueless as to which approach will result in a better performance

Comment: I recommend a quick read of chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's excellent book [SQL Antipatterns](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557). (You can read chapter 2 in the "Look Inside" preview of Amazon.).  Bottom line:  storing a delimited list of values in a single column is a bad idea. As long as appropriate indexes are created, storing the individual values in separate rows is not a performance problem.

Comment: One extra point. If you ever do store a delimited list in a field (almost never a good idea) then use a comma as the delimited. While performance will still be poor (due to the impossibility of usefully indexing it) you can at least use the FIND_IN_SET() function

Comment: If I chose to store a "delimited list of values" in a single database column...  I would *only* do that if I had a guarantee that the database would never need to query or maintain the contents of that column. In terms of the database, as if that column was *always* treated as a *single* value. Like it were a .jpg image, or a .wav file. The client can retrieve the entire value, and the client can store the entire value. The  client will *never* request that the database: perform a comparison on the column, never ask if a value is "in the list", never add or remove a value from the list, etc.

Comment: @spencer7593 That is exactly my requirement. The 'numbers' column would contain a list of phone numbers. All that was needed was to get them and just send messages to each of them. Thanks for the insights :)

Comment: @NavinNagpal: At the risk of being redundant, just to be clear. I agree with the answers that say "store each number in a separate row". That's the party line, that's critical component to how the "relational model" works. (Each column should contain a *single* value.)  If you ever find yourself needing to answer the question "which products have a particular number in its numbers_list", or needing to "remove a particular number from this products numbers_list"... then storing the delimited list is going to turn out to be wrong.

Comment: @spencer7593 True that ! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing anything about Laravel, but something about databases my general answer would be that you should almost never store more that one item in a single record in a relational database - doing so breaks the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) and makes the data very hard to work with, so the second approach is definitively better. Maybe you should read up on how relational databases function and about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

If you let a record hold more than one discrete item you can neither maintain relations between tables nor use indexing to increase performance, and you lose a lot of other important properties too.